# Why am I receiving an error when trying to push application to IBM cloud?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I would like to push a simple Flask app to IBM cloud by using the following command:

```
%%bash
cd /resources/labs/CV0101EN/CV0101EN-capstone-project/app
ibmcloud app push
```

Unfortunately I receive an error during the process.
By looking at the error I assume that for some reason, there was a problem with python installation, but I have no clue what is the cause of that. Does anyone know where is the issue here ? I would be grateful for any advice.

**Installation log:**

```
Cell xxx creating container for instance yyy
   Cell xxx successfully created container for instance yyy
   Downloading app package...
   Downloaded app package (14.8K)
   -----> Python Buildpack version 1.7.6
   -----> Supplying Python
          **ERROR** Could not install python: no match found for 3.6.8 in [2.7.16 2.7.17 3.5.7 3.5.9 3.6.9 3.6.10 3.7.5 3.7.6 3.8.0 3.8.1]
   Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run all supply scripts: exit status 14
   Exit status 223
   Cell xxx stopping instance yyy
   Cell xxx destroying container for instance yyy
   Cell ef638021-80ae-4fa7-b9d7-fca401983c23 successfully destroyed container for instance yyy
FAILED
```

**Below is the error that appears in my Jupiter notebook.**

```
Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-b9984b2b336d> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('bash', '', 'cd /resources/labs/CV0101EN/CV0101EN-capstone-project/app\nibmcloud app push\n')

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2360             with self.builtin_trap:
   2361                 args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2362                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2363             return result
   2364 

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py in named_script_magic(line, cell)
    140             else:
    141                 line = script
--> 142             return self.shebang(line, cell)
    143 
    144         # write a basic docstring:

</home/jupyterlab/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-110> in shebang(self, line, cell)

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py in shebang(self, line, cell)
    243             sys.stderr.flush()
    244         if args.raise_error and p.returncode!=0:
--> 245             raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, cell, output=out, stderr=err)
    246 
    247     def _run_script(self, p, cell, to_close):

CalledProcessError: Command 'b'cd /resources/labs/CV0101EN/CV0101EN-capstone-project/app\nibmcloud app push\n'' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to size limitations, buildpacks cannot contain all versions of Python ever created. As you can see in the output, the buildpack is telling you the version you requested and which versions are supported.

> **ERROR** Could not install python: no match found for 3.6.8 in [2.7.16 2.7.17 3.5.7 3.5.9 3.6.9 3.6.10 3.7.5 3.7.6 3.8.0 3.8.1]

The short answer is that you need to specify a version in `runtime.txt` that is in the list of supported versions. That could be `3.6.9` or `3.6.10`.

A better solution though is to not specify a specific version, and to specify a branch. If you were to set `3.6.x` then you won't encounter this problem again in 2 months when 3.6.9 is no longer supported by the buildpack (buildpacks are constantly upgrading dependencies so you get the latest security & bug fixes).

With `3.6.x`, you will just get the latest version of the 3.6 branch that is supported by the buildpack. In the example above, that would result in 3.6.10 being installed. In two months when there is a 3.6.11, you'll automatically get 3.6.11.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/index.html#runtime

Comment: Yes I figured that out after a while although your additional advice and detailed explanation is very appreciated. Have a great day Daniel !

Answer (score -1):

Change of the Python version in a runtime.txt file that was located in the project's directory resolved the issue. Python got installed successfully.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. Can you paste the snippet of code you changed in `runtime.txt` ?

Comment: It was a simple change from python version  3.6.8 to 3.6.9 and it worked.